# Ruby: How to store each line from many .txt files into one variable

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have to store several lines from .txt files which are located in different directories into variable but I don't know how.

This is my code for printing every line from those .txt files and it works fine, but I don't know how to store them into one variable.

```
Dir.chdir "/path/to/dir"
Dir.glob("**/*.{mo,txt}").each do |filename|
  File.open(filename, "r") do |f|
    f.each_line do |line|
            puts line
        end
    end
end
```

I'm beginner in ruby so please help!!

Comment: Is your question, "How can I construct an array that contains every line of every file contained in a given directory?"? If so, and if files in sub-directories are to be included as well, "How can I construct an array that contains every line of every file contained in a given directory and in all of its sub-directories?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array would be perfect for this

```
array = []
Dir.chdir "/path/to/dir"
Dir.glob("**/*.{mo,txt}").each do |filename|

  File.open(filename, "r") do |f|
    f.each_line do |line|
      array << line.gsub(/[\r\n]+/, ' ')
    end
  end
end
```

If you want an alternative solution:

```
Dir.glob("**/*.{mo,txt}").each do |filename|
  File.foreach(filename).map { |line| array << line.gsub(/[\r\n]+/, ' ') }
end
```

the regex being subbed on line is to remove any unwanted newline characters. So a file consisting of

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

without the regex, would fill your array with:

```
["1\n", "2\n", "3\n", "4\n", "5\n"]
```

with the regex, would fill your array with:

```
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Problem solved! :D Regex is not required but it's good to know.

Comment: `array.concat(IO.readlines(filename, chomp: true))` would work as well.